# after changing the code in a php file on wordpress the website doesn't get the update

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

i am creating a website using wordpress  and i am adding custom php files and templates to the selected theme .

the problem is that when i change the code the website doesn't take the updated code.

i have a cache plugins (**WP super cache**) and i empty the cache but still doesn't get the update. i am using the Mozilla browser.

what cloud be the problem and how to fix it ??

i tried to change this line of code but still not getting the updated code on the website.

## old code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
```

## new code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter **** your Name" required/>
```

Comment: please try to clear browser cache or else try different browser or private window

Comment: can you write this as an answer to vote up  because you answer was right

Comment: Sure i will write as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its due to the cache issue.You will follow this steps to remove cache.

1. Disable caching plugins
2. Purge cache from browser.Click the Refresh button on the browser toolbar or press the F5 key on your keyboard.
3. Try different browser or private window.